# drag image and put it at desired location in screen

Tags: android, animation, uiimageview, android-linearlayout

I have five linear layouts..I put one image in centerlayout,now if user click on pink layout image should transfer in that layout,i used animation for that,can any one help me with that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener,OnDragListener{
private static final String LOGCAT = null;
private LinearLayout centers;
private ImageView imageview1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    centers=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.centLayout);
    imageview1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    findViewById(R.id.textView1).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.pinkLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.yellowLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.blackLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.centLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.redLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    centers.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            imageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             imageview1.bringToFront();
                                int y = (int)event.getY();
                                int x = (int)event.getX();

                                imageview1.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
                                imageview1.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
                                imageview1.layout(x, y, x+48, y+48);

            return false;

        }
    });

}
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { 
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
          view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
          view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


          return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}  
public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
      int action = dragevent.getAction();
      switch (action) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
          Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
          Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into "+layoutview.toString());
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
          Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from "+layoutview.toString());
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped");
        View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        owner.removeView(view);
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
        container.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
              Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag ended");
          break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      return true;
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pinkLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="#FF8989"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/blackLayout"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pinkLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/yellowLayout"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"

     >
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/centLayout"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pinkLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/yellowLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackLayout"

    android:background="#D30000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

     >
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/spadeone"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"

   />

    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/redLayout"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pinkLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/yellowLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/blackLayout"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
     >
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/yellowLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"

    android:background="#FFCC00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     >
</LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

move_up.xml

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
   android:fromXDelta="0%p"


    android:toYDelta="-65%p"
    android:duration="800" />

 </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Rect coord of the specific location and check if the dragged item coordinates clash with the location Rect coords. You can use Rect.contains() api for checking. If it returns true, you can show the alert.

```
if (locationRect.contains(drag.left, drag.top, drag.right, drag.bottom)) {
    // do what you want to do now
}
```

To track the positioning of your drag view, add the following to your drag listener,

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
x_cord = (int) event.getX(); // add to your dragEvent
y_cord = (int) event.getY(); // add to your dragEvent

case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION :
x_cord = (int) event.getX(); // add to your dragEvent
y_cord = (int) event.getY(); // add to your dragEvent
```